# Insert text BEFORE the "tag" title

Tags: tags

I'd like to insert text BEFORE the "tag" title.

So, I am using Categories and Tags and I when I click into one of my "tag" archives the title of the page is simply the word of the "tag" so in my example it is "New York"

What I would like to do is insert text BEFORE "New York"

I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'custom_tag_archive_title' );
/**
 * Remove archive labels.
 * 
 * @param  string $title Current archive title to be displayed.
 * @return string        Modified archive title to be displayed.
 */
function custom_tag_archive_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_tag() ) {
        $title = single_tag_title( 'Conferences In&nbsp;', false );
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Now, the interesting thing is that I did the same for my categories and it works great. The function I am using is this:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'custom_taxonomy_archive_title' );
/**
 * Remove archive labels.
 * 
 * @param  string $title Current archive title to be displayed.
 * @return string        Modified archive title to be displayed.
 */
function custom_taxonomy_archive_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_tax('us_state') ) {
        $title = single_term_title( 'Conferences In&nbsp;', false );
    }
    elseif ( is_tax('country') ) {
        $title = single_term_title( 'Conferences In&nbsp;', false );
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Any ideas why the "tag" (which is a regular "tag") doesn't load the text before?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I skipped this and figured out the best way as Pseudo CSS (I believe it is called)

```
body.tag .page-title:before {
    content: 'Conferences In ';
}
```

^ this works well